# Bash - How to wrap values of the first line of a csv file with quotations

Tags: bash, csv, quotation-marks

Line 1 of a csv file has the values separated by a comma like so:

```
word1,word2,word3,word4,word5
```

but needs to be wrapped with quotations like below:

```
"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"
```

I would like a command to address line 1 only and leave the rest of the file alone.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus for the help. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file.csv
word1,word2,word3,word4,word5
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```

To put quotes around the items in the first line only:

```
$ sed '1 { s/^/"/; s/,/","/g; s/$/"/ }' file.csv
"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```

How it works

- `1 { ... }`

  This tells sed to perform the commands in braces only on line 1.
- `s/^/"/`

  This puts a quote at the start of the line.
- `s/,/","/g`

  This replaces each comma with quote-comma-quote.
- `s/$/"/`

  This puts a quote at the end of the line.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**awk** alternative approach:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{ gsub(/[^,]+/,"\"&\"",$0) }1' file
```

- `NR==1` - consider only the 1st record

Comment: Thanks Roman for sharing your knowledge with me. Well appreciated.